# Server Shutdown-Too Hot, but no hot

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, hp-proliant

I have an HP DL360e Gen8 server that boots up, lets me log in then powers off because I get a message that the server is running too hot. When booting, its 71F ambient tempeture. Any one that can help me either see actual running temp or how to disable this? I'm new at this, so please dont roast me to the moon and back.

OS used is Server 2012 R2

Comment: Are you using HP disks in the server, or third-party drives?

Comment: Log in to iLO and check to see if any fans have failed.

Comment: I'm running Raid 5 with AXIOM 10K for an array and HP 15K used for main OS on a Raid 1

Comment: @Chris You shouldn't be using non-HP disks in this setup. I'm not familiar with Axiom drives, but this server model has a requirement for HP-approved drives.

Comment: That's a good point. A non-approved drive may report sensor data that appears out-of-range to the RAID controllers despite real-world temperatures within the drive being fine. There are all kinds of other inconsistencies that can occur when using "any ol' drive".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I downloaded the most uptodate SSP from HP (costs money) and after updating firmware for all devices on server, issue was resolved.

Sorry for the troubles...

Answer (score 1):

Ambient temperature sensors only report ambient temperature, not the temperature of any components. Check all of your other sensors (especially the CPU sensors, as that's typically the hottest component on  a board). You can do this easily using the iLO or iLOM BMC controller on your system board, which will have a web interface that you can collect this data from. You'll need to start the node before some sensors will become active.

Answer (score 0):

@SmallLoanOf1M is right, the iLO or BMC monitors should be able to tell you what components are actually overheating. If for some reason you don't have access to those, and Windows runs long enough to install software, you could use some hardware monitoring application such as [Open Hardware Monitor](http://openhardwaremonitor.org/) instead.